# How are previous and next links for a page determined in Sphinx (Read the Docs using mostly restructured text)?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, read-the-docs

We're using ReadTheDocs for our project's documentation and i can't figure out what logic it's using to come up with what the next and previous pages are.

It seems to be quite random in certain cases, for instance [this page](https://docs.drutopia.org/en/latest/development.html) for its next page jumps backwards in the table of contents [two spaces](https://docs.drutopia.org/en/latest/drutopia-code-of-conduct.html).  (Update: Hmm.. Most other pages seem to make sense, so maybe the question is what's different or weird about [either](https://gitlab.com/drutopia/documentation/blob/master/development.md) of [these two](https://gitlab.com/drutopia/documentation/blob/master/drutopia-code-of-conduct.rst)?

I have looked and looked and cannot find any documentation on what it's supposed to do, or how to modify it.  Closest i found was [in mkdocs](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/configuration/#documentation-layout) but we're [using Sphinx](https://gitlab.com/drutopia/documentation/-/blob/master/conf.py).

Comment: Do a `make clean` and `make html`. Look for any warnings or errors about duplicates. Your [build log](https://readthedocs.org/projects/drutopia/builds/10899759/) shows some warnings for the `make html` command about `contributing.rst:2: WARNING: Duplicate explicit target name: "sign up as a supporter".` and inconsistent heading levels. Headings appear in the navigation and can cause the funkiness you describe.